# Use SAST result in subsequent GitLab pipeline stage

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to utilize a parser I wrote to, use an artifact from SAST analyze in GitLab CI. The parser is run in a stage after the SAST (`test`) stage. But when the parser job is run the SAST artifact is being removed, according to the job log.

That's my `gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
stages:
 - test
 - report

include:
  - template: Security/SAST.gitlab-ci.yml

sast:
  stage: test
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - gl-sast-report.json
    expire_in: 1 week

report_creation:
  stage: report
  image: gl-sast-parser
  script:
    - ...
  dependencies:
    - sast
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - gl-sast-report.html
```

And that's the part from the log of the `report_creation` log where the artifact from previous stage seems to be deleted:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z42og.png)

I already had run `find` and other cmd tools in the `script` part of `report_creation` job to find out where the artifact is located without any success. Also I check various similar questions here, but their solutions didn't work for me. Could anybody help me finding the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gitlab CI SAST access to gl-sast-report.json artifact in subsequent stage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64232630/gitlab-ci-sast-access-to-gl-sast-report-json-artifact-in-subsequent-stage)

Comment: @Egor Yes, I tried this already. The artifacts are still being removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of fumbling around I found the solution that worked for me. I changed the `dependencies` configuration from the parent `sast` job to the `semgrep-sast` job (which is the one I currently only use). So my `gitlab-ci.yml` now looks like this:

```
stages:
 - test
 - report

include:
  - template: Security/SAST.gitlab-ci.yml

semgrep-sast:
  stage: test
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - gl-sast-report.json
    expire_in: 1 week

report_creation:
  stage: report
  image: gl-sast-parser
  script:
    - ...
  dependencies:
    - semgrep-sast
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - gl-sast-report.html
```